# Doctrine2 Mysql charset

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i have an doctrine2 orm and it generates my DB-Tables with another charset then my default mysql charset is.

how can i change the charset of the generated orm tables?

in the doctrine documentation they write, that it should be the same than the mysql-default. but it isnt.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found something like this:

```
// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'dbname' => '****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(
        1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

i have to try it.